# Right time to put hotdog rolls into oven

Tags: rising, proofing, rolls

I am confused about this. On proofing hot dog rolls, when is the right time to put the rolls into the oven? Should I wait till the yeast is done proofing in which case the rolls become too undesirably big or should I put them in the oven when the size of the rolls are to my preference?

Comment: Neither? Can you please explain in more detail, what you are doing and what you want to accomplish?

Comment: If the rolls "become too big" start with "make them smaller" when forming...

Answer (score 2):

Rolls are no different from other types of yeast bread in terms of the general procedure for bulk fermentation and proofing. Obviously, each bread has its own characteristics, gluten development, fermentation time, etc. and I'd need to see your recipe to give more specific advice since there are many different ways to make hot dog buns (amount of fat, milk, sugar, etc.).

In terms of fermentation and proofing for yeast breads in general, you typically want to ferment as long and slow as possible for flavor development (that is, retarding rather than fermenting at room temp), often with folds, but usually hot dog buns would be a much shorter bulk ferment (maybe an hour) and then you would shape them and then let them proof (maybe 45 minutes depending on the temperature, humidity, etc.).

They should about double in size, and if you poke them with a finger (first dipped in flour), the indentation should stay. They will increase in size, maybe 20-40%, during baking, so make them a little smaller than the final size you're after. You'll have to practice a few times to get everything right. You'll get a little more oven spring if you bake with steam.